# Initialization of structs used as ref output parameters in native methods

Tags: c#, .net-core, pinvoke

How do native methods initialize structures that they return through an `out IntPtr` parameter?

Given the following native code:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", EntryPoint = "bar", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int GetBars(out int count, out IntPtr output);
```

and the following struct definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public readonly record struct BarOut
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 21)]
    public readonly string FieldA;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public readonly bool FieldB;
}
```

the managed implementation is able to make the native call and read all the structs found at the pointer.

The entire code base also works with regular structs such as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
public struct BarOut
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 21)]
    public string FieldA;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public bool FieldB;
}
```

I cannot find any documentation that describes how the structs are initialized and therefore  I am not clear whether these two output definitions are safely equivalent where the only difference is the record is immutable.

Does substituting records in the codebase present any problems?

Comment: its a c calling convention. its up to the function implementation

Comment: The *record* keyword is just syntax sugar in C#, after the compiler is done with it there is no distinction from a class or struct anymore.  So initialization is not special either, the pinvoke marshaller doesn't know any better than that both declarations are identical.  Best to avoid *record* to avoid confuzzling the reader.  And avoid IntPtr, declare the method as int GetBars(out int count, [Out] out BarOut output).  The [Out] attribute is necessary to tell the pinvoke marshaller that it must copy the data back after the call.

Comment: How do I free the memory allocated by the native call?

Comment: While I am not clear on freeing allocated memory, this seems to work for the native methods without a `int count` parameter that return `T`, but for those methods that return `T[]` and use the count to indicate how much memory to read, only initialize the array with one instance even when several exist at the pointer location.